# Set cover problem aproximate solution NP-hardness

Tags: computational-complexity

I need to prove that for some $\epsilon$ the approximate solution of [Set Cover Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) with precision $\epsilon$ is an NP-hard problem.

Can I present this problem as a VERTEX-COVER problem and then reduce MIN-3SAT to VERTEX-COVER and show that for some $\epsilon$ the approximate solution of VERTEX-COVER with precision $\epsilon$ is an NP-hard problem?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: @Algebruh I have tried to use the reducibility of the Vertex Cover problem to it.